# How to have seperate builds with different screens/UI dev and product build with one code base in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, build, flutter

I am building cross-platform with Flutter using Android Studio.

During my development process, I would like to use development tools like 
[Flutter Redux Dev Tool](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux_dev_tools) which shows a debug screen right on the application UI like this

[image: Flutter Redux Dev Tool]

Or I can have my own debugging modules in the form of custom-styled `print` statements which I insert into different places in my codes.

I don't want to have to comment these debugging code out and/or switching out the appropriate UIs every time I need to build a product version

Are there ways to do this?

PS: I heard about build variants on Android Studio, is this the industrial way to solve this? If so, how to use it with Flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use different entry-point files

```
flutter run -t lib/main_config1.dart
flutter build apk -t lib/main_config1.dart
...
```

You can then configure your application with different services (for logging or similar) depending on the requirements.

The `--flavor` options provides further ways for customization.

See also https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36

Comment: Thank you. I read the article. It is nice to learn a new technique. The article says there's no way to use flavor in Dart code and provides a work around, which is a switch and for each different parts in the flavors, you have to use the "Config" file. It works but it seems a lot more work and I would have to think about how to structure the project with this new Config layer (e.g. If I have many debugging code, I would need many of this `Config.getSomething` statements, maybe nested...). I was hoping for something like an annotation you can insert right into DART code. But thanks again.

Comment: Dart doesn't provide anything like macros which would make this easy. Configurable (conditional) imports are planned for future versions which might help.